# Executing sqlalchamy but don't see the changes in the DB

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

i have a DF that has a ID (specifically GKGRECORDID) and a column that i want to update called GCAM. i execute the following command but it doesn't change any record in the DB. as i know `connection.execute` command should execute the update. Unfortunately i can't find the error.

```
 connection_string = 'vv'
  engine = create_engine(connection_string)
    
   with engine.connect() as connection:
        for index, row in merged.iterrows():
             update_statement = text("""
              UPDATE [GDELT].[dbo].[GKG]
              SET GCAM = :column
              WHERE GKGRECORDID = :ID
                            """)
           connection.execute(update_statement, {'column': row['GCAM'], 'ID': row['GKGRECORDID']})
           print(row['GKGRECORDID'], row['GCAM'])
```

Comment: Try using `with engine.begin() as connection:` instead of `with engine.connect() as connection:`